# Не работает redirect в связке laravel + vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, redirect

Осваиваю Laravel. Сделал простую форму (просмотр/редактирование/удаление) всё работает.
Появилось желание сделать валидацию на стороне клиента. Сделал форму через vue-component, данные получаю через axios.get. Самописная валидация на уникальность работает. Данные сохраняются в БД, но не работает редирект на страницу со списком всех записей.

Что есть:
1) Сохранение данных во vue-component

```
onSubmit: function () {
  this.urlUpdate = '/units/'+this.data.id+'/update'
  axios.post(this.urlUpdate, {'code': this.code, 'name': this.name })
    .then (function (response) {
      console.log(response);})
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);});
}
```

2. Маршрут

```
Route::post('/units/{id}/update', 'UnitController@update')->name('unit-update');
```

3. Контроллер

```
public function update($id, Request $req)
{  $unit = Unit::find ($id);
    $unit->code =$req->input('code');
    $unit->name =$req->input('name');
    $unit->save();
    return redirect()->route('units');
}
```

В обычной форме всё переходит и работает. Через axios.post данные в БД пишутся, но остаюсь на той же странице, а в качестве response получают html-код страницы на которую нужно перейти. Она вся выводится в консоль.
Как правильно реализовать переход? Смотреть в сторону vue-router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vue-component

```
   onSubmit: function () {
      this.urlUpdate = '/units/'+this.data.id+'/update'
      axios.post(this.urlUpdate, {'code': this.code, 'name': this.name })
        .then (function (response) {
          console.log(response);

        if (response.data.href !== undefined) {
          location.href = response.data.href
        } else {
          location.reload(true);
        }

    })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);});
    }
```

Контроллер

```
public function update($id, Request $req)
{  
$result = [];

$unit = Unit::find ($id);
    $unit->code =$req->input('code');
    $unit->name =$req->input('name');
    $unit->save();

$result['href'] = route('units');
return response()->json($result)

}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает!

Answer (score 0):

use Vue-Router

Vue Component

```
this.$router.push('your redirect link')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Буду пробовать